# TI Basic Index Error when looping through List

Tags: sorting, ti-basic

I'm trying to implement insertion sort in TI-BASIC on the TI-84 and have nearly been successful. My solution sorts all but the first element of the list. In order to work properly, I believe this line:

`While C>1 and L1(C)>V`

needs to be

`While C>0 and L1(C)>V`

However this creates an error because apparently TI-BASIC is checking `L1(0)` even though we are exiting the loop before getting there.

Could someone please explain how to avoid this problem and make the code work?

This is my code:

```
0->dim(L1
randIntNoRep(1,10,10)->L1
For(I,2,10)
    L1(I)->V
    I-1->C
    While C>1 and L1(C)>V
        L1(C)->L1(C+1)
        C-1->C
    End
    V->L1(C+1)
End
Disp L1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, i found the solution. The trick is if C=1 you can't have it in a while loop you have to have it in an If statement. Place this block of code after your while loop:

```
If C=1 and L1(C)>V
Then
L1(C)->L1(C+1)
C-1->C
End
```

The whole thing:

```
SetUpEditor L1
0->dim(L1
randIntNoRep(1,10,10)->L1
For(I,2,10)
    L1(I)->V
    I-1->C
    While C>1 and L1(C)>V
        L1(C)->L1(C+1)
        C-1->C
    End
    If C=1 and L1(C)>V
    Then
        L1(C)->L1(C+1)
        C-1->C
    End
    V->L1(C+1)
End
Disp L1
```